# Any issue with GFCI outlet touching sides of outlet extender?

Tags: electrical, gfci, junction-box

I have to extend a single gang outlet box to account for added depth from beadboard wainscoting. The box is PVC and so is the outlet extender. The problem is, the outlet is a GFCI and it is very snug in the outlet extender. It touches on all sides. Is this acceptable? Should be safe from shorts because the extender and box are PVC correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't take any chances. Give the receptacle a couple of wraps of tape around its perimeter, to cover up the screw terminals for sure.

The other way to solve a "GFCI in a hard location" problem is to install the GFCI device instead in a location *between* this one and the service panel... then feed this outlet off the LOAD terminals of the other GFCI.  It can be a recep at an earlier location, a deadfront at a new location (e.g. next to the panel), or a GFCI breaker.